# Scala interpolate String from variable

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

String interpolation works fine in this case:

```
val name = "Bill"
val result = s"My Name is ${name}"
```

When I introduce it to the variable it didn't get interpolated value:

```
val name = "Bill"
val greeting = "My Name is ${name}"
val result = s"${greeting}"
```

Direct wrapping of `greeting` is not appropriate solution, I must handle greeting like a plain String.

Comment: Interpolating `greeting` makes no sense, as it's already a string

Comment: @pacman What is the question?

Comment: Do you want a function `(name: String) => s"My Name is ${name}"`? Or do you want `name` to be bound dynamically to whichever variable called name is in scope at the time you call `s"${greeting}"`? Hint: go with the function either way. It's far less confusing.

Comment: @Tim My question is: how to evaluate usual string as interpolated?

Comment: @Jasper-M I had never mentioned any function which you provided in your comment, I want to evaluate usual String as an interpolated.

Comment: There's often a difference between what people say they want, what people really want, and what people need.

Comment: Firstly, you're missing the `s` from before the string in `greeting`, so it's just printing "My Name is ${name}" instead of "My Name is Bill" (not sure if this is just a typo or actually an error in your code). Secondly, why are you not just doing `val result = greeting`? Wrapping it in another string seems redundant.

Comment: I think this is a well-formed question. It's obvious what `result` is expected, and it's OK not to care what the type of `greeting` is, just as users don't care what the expression `s"$greeting"` actually does.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260864/string-interpolation-in-scala-2-10-how-to-interpolate-a-string-variable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655603/scala-string-interpolator-on-existing-string-with-embedded-variables, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888933/calling-a-string-interpolator-on-a-variable-in-scala, probably more.

Comment: did you find solution for this question?

Answer (score 6):

String interpolation in Scala does not compose in the way you expect.

The issue for this [has been debated](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6010). Folks want it, but folks don't always get what they want.

You could imagine writing some macros that work in concert. One defines a function taking a string, the other knows how to interpolate it by invoking it with the correctly named value in scope.

Also worth adding that interpolation is not a generic runtime templating  mechanism. For example, you can't read strings from a file of the form `"$greeting"` and run interpolation substitutions on it.

Answer (score 3):

- There is an unused variable `name` with value `"Bill"`
- There is a `String` variable `greeting` which contains characters `['M','y',' ','n','a','m','e',' ','i','s',' ','$','{','n','a','m','e','}']` (completely unrelated to the variable `name`, the four characters `'n'`, `'a'`, `'m'`, `'e'` have no possibility of getting anywhere near compiler's symbol table, which is good).
- There is a variable `result`, whose value is computed by string interpolation from `greeting`. Since

  ```
  val y = "whatever"
  val x = s"${y}"
  ```

  must always result in variable `x` having the same content as variable `y`, the variable `result` ends up having the same value as `greeting`, namely `"My Name is ${name}"`.

If the compiler tried to execute every substring that looks somewhat like Scala code, this would result in total chaos, because every time something can leak from the realm of `String`-data into the realm of executable code, it makes the code vulnerable for all kind of injection exploits.