# Value not populated for given string in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using property file to pass sql query in spark scala, my property file like this.

```scala
spark.query=select '$env' from table_name limit 5
```

In spark code

```
val env="dev"
val query=sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.query");

println(query);

spark.sql(s"""$query""");
```

But here it's not talking value for dev my output is like below:

select `$env` from `table_name =>$env` value not populating.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655112/scala-interpolate-string-from-variable

Comment: First, important thing is that you don't need to put a semicolon (;) in Scala